# How to remove all text from an EditText on button click in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to know how can I erase all text from an EditText by clicking a button. E.g. - Just like a calculator has a button is `c` that clears all text in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all text by adding this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editText.getText().clear();
            }
        });
```